# Change link in Joomla after domain change

Tags: joomla, hyperlink, smf

I changed the domain of my site (joomla+jfusion+smf)

Some links to  smf haven't changed.

In the old site they were 
`www.olddomain/en/oldforumfolder/`
now they are 
`www.newdomain/en/oldforumfolder/`
instead of 
`www.newdomain/en/newforumfolder/`

Is there a way to  change them all together?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [reReplacer](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/rereplacer)*

*NOTE: This is not the best option.

Better option is, you should use some editor (like TextPad) to locate all the occurrences of the `olddomain` and replace them with `newdomain`